# If $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra with no nontrivial maps $m/m^2\to k$ for any $m\subset A$, is $A\cong k^n$ as modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra, for an algebraically closed field $k$. Suppose that for any maximal ideal $m\subset A$, the only homomorphism of $k$-modules from $m/m^2$ to $k$ is the null homomorphism. Is it true that $A\cong k^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$?

As usual write $A$ as $k[x_1,\dots,x_m]/I$. *If I had, for every maximal ideal $m\subset A$, that $m^2\subseteq I$*, could I prove that the only elements in $k[x_1,\dots,x_m]/I$, not belonging to $k$, are (equivalence classes of) polynomials of degree $1$?

If $I\subseteq (x_1,\dots,x_n)$, by the assumption in *italics*, the equivalence class $\bar {x_i}$ of every $x_i$, in $A$, is such that $\bar {x_i}^2=0$. So in this situation I would say that $A=k \oplus k\bar{x_1}\oplus\dots \oplus k\bar{x_n}$. However if I don't have $I\subseteq (x_1,\dots,x_n)$, I cannot say that $(\bar{x_1},\dots,\bar{x_n})$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, and I cannot say that the $\bar {x_i}^2$ are zero. This last issue doesn't  seem serious, but the assumption in italics is crucial: is it true though? It seemed intuitive but I tried to prove it for a while without success. Thank for any clarify

Comment: Please make your titles more descriptive and informative. "Exercise with finitely generated $k$-algebra" could mean almost anything - it's much better to be more specific. See [choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) for more advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. The condition you write is equivalent to zero-dimensional tangent spaces at every closed point of $\operatorname{Spec} A$. Since $\dim_{A/m} m/m^2$ is at least the Krull dimension of $A_m$, we have that $A_m$ is dimension zero for all maximal ideals of $A$. Since the Krull dimension of a ring is the supremum of the dimensions of it's local rings at maximal primes, we have that $A$ is of Krull dimension zero. But $A$ is also noetherian, being a finitely-generated $k$-algebra. As noetherian rings of dimension zero are artinian, and artinian $k$-algebras are finite-dimensional as $k$-vector spaces, this finishes the proof.

Comment: I don't understand well the first part, the geometric one. I mean, it's clear that for every maximal ideal $m\subset A$, the Krull dimension of $A_m$ is less or equal to the dimension of $m/m^2$ as a $k$-module (that here is $0$). Then you used that if $krdim A_m=0$ for every maximal ideal $m$, we have $krdim A=0$? (If yes I didn't know it's true, does it hold only when $k$ is algebraically closed or for algebras over a field in general?)

Comment: I cleaned that up a bit. The statement I really wanted to use was that the Krull dimension of $A$ is the supremum of the dimension of $A_m$ over all maximal ideals $m\subset A$. (Proof: consider a chain of inclusions of prime ideals of maximal length, which must end in a maximal ideal. Localizing at this maximal ideal shows that $\dim A_m=\dim A$.)

Comment: Thanks now it is clear

Comment: I’m pretty sure $A \cong k^n$ as algebras, not just modules. That is, $A$ is reduced. This is a local question, so assume $A$ is local. Then by Nakayama’s lemma, $m/m^2 = 0$ implies $m=0$ and so $A = k$.

Comment: @KReiser can I ask one thing: the fact that $krdim(A_m)\le dim_{A/m}(A_m)$ is true even if $A_m$ is not regular? Or it is a trivial check that I missed. Thanks for your patience

Comment: @Dr.Scotti The correct version of that statement, $\dim_{Krull} A_m \leq \dim_{A/m} m/m^2$, is true for all noetherian local rings and follows by Nakayama + Krull's Hauptidealsatz: the RHS is the minimum number of generators of $m$ as an $A$-module by Nakayama, which is an upper bound for the height of $m$ by Krull's Hauptidealsatz, but the height of $m$ is the Krull dimension of $A_m$.

Comment: The previous comment tells you exactly how to reach that conclusion. If you're having issues understanding that, please ask a new question. I think the conversation in these comments has reached the conclusion of its usefulnes, good day.