# Reference request for regularity of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

I'm following a commutative algebra course that can be covered by Atiyah-MacDonald, except for the last part about regular rings, that leans towards geometry. We just saw differential and derivations, and the Zariski tangent space, basically. To make a concrete example, Atiyah-MacDonald doesn't contain the first part of the answer to the linked question; the notes of the course confuse me sometimes, so I'd like an actual textbook. As I said, I don't think we saw any advanced result in this part, I'd just want a reference to convince me well of arguments like the one in the cited answer. Thank you in advance

[If $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra with no nontrivial maps $m/m^2\to k$ for any $m\subset A$, is $A\cong k^n$ as modules?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4332749/if-a-is-a-finitely-generated-k-algebra-with-no-nontrivial-maps-m-m2-to-k)

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're looking for. Maybe look for other texts on commutative algebra (e.g. Eisenbud, Gathmann, ...) or start learning algebraic geometry (e.g. Vakil).

Comment: @QiZhu I looked at Eisenbud and Gathmann but don't match very well with my course; I found that Matsumura's commutative ring theory is quite good for the part on the derivations, but I don't understand from what text the results that link regularity, normality, DVR, dimension of tangent space could come from.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you are looking for, Eisenbud and Gathmann cover a great amount of results concerning regularity, normality, DVR. You may understand tangent spaces better once you studied algebraic geometry, e.g. chapter 12 in Vakil starts with tangent space and regularity in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Chapters 11, 12 of Vakil actually  seem good; anyway I'll make you two examples of results that I see on my notes and can't find anywhere (I know that they could be contained in a lot of texts, but maybe they are so diluited that I don't see them just looking at the book). One is that for a $1$-dimensional local noetherian ring $A$ the conditions of being regular, normal, or DVR are equivalent; the other is that $\operatorname{dim}A\le\operatorname{dim}_k m/m^2$, where $m$ is the maximal ideal of $A$ and $k:=\operatorname{Frac}A$.

Comment: Both of your examples can be found in Gathmann (chapter 11, 12) and in fact almost every introduction to commutative algebra contain these.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't find them in Gathmann, do you mean the chapters about 27 lines in the cubic surface and schemes (that are never mentioned in my course though)? Anyway you said that they are in most introductions to commutative algebra, but do you confirm that they aren't in Atiyah-MacDonald?

Comment: Sorry, I mean Gathmann‘s notes on commutative algebra, not on algebraic geometry. I haven‘t read Atiyah-Macdonald, but no I do not confirm that, see Proposition 9.2.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, the notes of Gathmann seem really good! For the proposition 9.2 you're right, I meant to say that only the second example isn't (I didn't find it) on Atiyah-MacDonald.

Comment: It is a bit hidden, but see Corollary 11.15.