# Basic question about Zariski tangent space

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and let $A$ be a Noetherian $k$-algebra. If $\Omega_{A/k}=0$, then $m/m^2=0$ for every maximal ideal $m\subset A$. Is the converse true?

I would say  yes, because any $k$-module of the form $m/m^2$ ($m$ maximal  as above) is isomorphic, and they are also all isomorphic to $\Omega_{A/k}\otimes_Ak$; however I realized that I don't understand how is  done the tensor product with $k$ over $A$ (I would understand the contrary). How is $k$ an $A$-module\algebra?

I cannot give you an actual reference because this result  is on the notes of my course, however it is written that, when $A$ is not Noetherian, the proof of this fact is in Matsumura's Commutative  ring theory, 25.2.

Comment: The answer to your overarching question is already contained in [this previous question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4332749/). Your proposed method of attack contains serious misunderstandings. Almost everything you say in your second paragraph is wrong: the $k$-algebra $k\times k[x]$ with maximal ideals $m_1=0\times k[x]$ and $m_2=k\times (x)$ has $m_1/m_1^2\cong 0$ and $m_2/m_2^2\cong k$ shows your argument cannot be correct. Recall that the data we need to make $k$ an $A$-algebra is a map $A\to k$. Can you see where you get these?

Comment: @KReiser (The comment that I just made on the other question was written before I read your response here, so it could be not linked). I see that  if $A\cong k[x_1,\dots , x_n]$,  we have $A\to k$ defined by $x_i\mapsto 0\ \forall  i$. However I still don't  understand the equality $m/m^2=\Omega_{A/k}\otimes_Ak$: if it  doesn't imply that all $m/m^2$ are isomorphic, does $\Omega_{A/k}\otimes_Ak$ depends on $m$? (I don't think)

Comment: You need to review your tensor products: the tensor product $\Omega_{A/k}\otimes_A k$ depends on the $A$-module structure on $k$! In your specific example of $A=k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ you get lucky, but you can't count on that in general. (What's going on is that when $A$ is smooth over $k$, $\Omega_{A/k}$ is locally free hence all the fibers on the same connected component are the same dimension; I showed an example with two different connected components.)

Comment: Ok, I understand your observation on the tensor products, but obviously not everything is clear. Since the only reference mentioned on my notes for this part is Matsumura's book, I'm going to use it, but any other good reference is welcome